# Summing Range in one Workbook and post it to another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need to sum the Range "C:C" in Workbook_A and paste the result into the Cells "B2" in Workbook_B. All I can find so far a really long and complicated solutions or some that first copy the range to Workbook_B and then do the summing up there. Is there a VBA one-liner to do this (Makro sitting in Workbook_B - the target)?

Copying a single cell from Workbook_A to Workbook_B works just fine:

```
Workbooks("Workbook_A.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Copy  Workbooks("Workbook_B.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
```

What doesn't work for me is:

```
Workbooks("Workbook_A.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("C:C")).Copy Workbooks("Workbook_B.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
```

Also doesn't work

```
Workbooks("Workbook_B.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = Workbooks("Workbook_A.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("C:C"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last one was nearly there. Try

```
Workbooks("Workbook_B.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.Sum(Workbooks("Workbook_A.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C"))
```

You need to fully define the range being summed - i.e. put everything inside the sum function.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @SJR his solution. You need to define your ranges. Example:

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Workbook_A")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set wb2 = Workbooks("Workbook_B")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws1
    ws2.Range("B2") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("C:C")) 'Or: .Evaluate("SUM(C:C)")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that's a lot neater (though OP wanted a one-liner).

Comment: It works for me when I have Workbook_B open - as the code runs in here - and the just start with Workbooks.Open "Workbook_A.xlsx". From then on it is only the code above.

Comment: @SJR, yes and therefor you have rightfully got the credits. For clarity I just added how to define ranges properly for future reference. A lot of those one liners become clunky quick, where references will work a lot smoother :)

Comment: You'll get no argument from me!